# "TypeError: Cannot read property 'launched' of null" in netbeans JSDT running jasmine tests

Tags: extjs, netbeans, jasmine, js-test-driver

I have setup a new ExtJs Project and want to test it with Netbeans and JSDT + adapter and an html test runner.

This is my file structure:

```
root  
- config  
 -- jsTestDriver.conf
- public  
 -- application  
 --- controller, model, store, view  
 -- ext // ExtJS lib.  
 -- test  
 --- lib  
 ---- jasmine + jstd-adapter  
 -- unit // Tests
```

The Jasmine spec runner (`/test/SpecRunner.html`) works fine, but the Netbeans JSTD shows the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'launched' of null

What is wrong?

Here's the application init code:

```js
Ext.onReady(function () {
    testApp = Ext.create('App.Application', {}, this);

    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmine.TrivialReporter());
    jasmine.getEnv().execute();
});

Ext.define('App.Application', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Application',
    // ...
```

and the tests:

```js
describe("Basic Assumptions", function () {
    it("has ExtJS4 loaded", function () {
        expect(Ext).toBeDefined();
        expect(Ext.getVersion()).toBeTruthy();
        expect(Ext.getVersion().major).toEqual(4);
    });
});

describe('BmKernel Application', function () {
    it('is launched', function () {
        expect(testApp).toBeDefined();

        expect(testApp.launched).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```